# How to handle "didReceiveIncomingCall" method for missed call in Sinch iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sinch

When the app is in background and user did not pick an incoming call. when the user came back to the app and `didReceiveIncomingCall` method called but I can't identify this call is missed a call or incoming call. Is there any way to differentiate **Missed call** and **Normal call**?

Answer (score 0):

If the call is not still reigning you should be process the notifications in the localnotification handler and look at the https://download.sinch.com/docs/iOS/latest/reference/html/Protocols/SINNotificationResult.html#//api/name/isValid

if the call is valid.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. My actual problem is that when the user opens the application without the tap on local notification at that time How could I handle it in 'didReceiveIncomingCall' Method?

Comment: @BhaveshPatel - Have you implemented PushKit for PushNotification?